# Is there a way to load an entity into an instance of derived class?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an entity and specialized class which is derived from the entity.
Is there any way (something tricky in JPA or spring) to let JPA create instances of the derived class instead of the entity class?

Otherwise I would need to create 'copy constructors' for each derived class. Or replace the inheritance by delegates wich seems to be clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If your entity has many subclasses that should be stored in the database differently, you can use JPA inheritance support (`@Inheritance`, etc).
- If your entity has only one subclass that should be always used in place of that entity, you can annotate that subclass as `@Entity`, and the entity - as `@MappedSuperclass`.
- If you want to achieve the previous case without modifying entities, you can use provider-specific solutions. For example, in Hibernate you can register a custom `Interceptor` and override its `instantiate()` method.

Comment: Thanks, your 2nd option is nice, but I need (due to caching requirements) serializable fields in the derived class which should not be persisted.

Comment: @stacker: You can mark these fields as `@Transient`, it doesn't affect serialization.

Comment: lol, seems that I confused transient annotation and the transient keyword.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a subset of the properties on an entity and do not want to change the entity then I suggest using a summary style query.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test_entity")
public class TestEntity extends BaseDomainObject<Long> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class TestSummary {

    private final Long id;

    private final String name;

    public TestSummary(Long id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then you can use a query like this:

```
select new TestSummary(te.id, te.name) from TestEntity te
```

JPA will generate a fast query that only loads the fields you want. I use this all the time when displaying a list of entities.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now using lomboks [delegate](http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html) annotation.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
   ...
}

public class MyBusinessObject {
   @Delegate
   private MyEntity entity;

   // other non persistent stuff
}
```